# How to print multiple sheets per paper while maintaining fixed page sizes in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I would like to print multiple pages of the size 7.5cm x 11 cm on an A4 Sheet. How do I achieve this? So far, I notice that scaling ruins my measurements e.g. at 8 sheets per page they are smaller than the set size and at 4 sheets per page, they are larger than the set size..Exporting to PDF didn't help either. Should I use Photoshop?

I've killed enough trees, I need your assistance! :)

Comment: I think it might be simplest to make an A4 page in word, insert a table where each cell has your desired size (7.5cm x 11cm) and copy the pages into those cells. Would that work for you?

Comment: That would work! How do I create a cell size in centimetres though?

Comment: Your question is about how to show cm and not inches, or how to set cell height/width?

Comment: How do I set cell size in centimeters? Or how do I estimate print size from cell height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to create a 4 cell table on the Word page, and input the "pages" content into those calls.

1. On an **A4** sized Word page, **Insert** > **Table** and insert a 2x2 table (4 cells total)
2. Select the whole table and go to the **Table Layout** tab, and enter `4.33"` for Height and `2.95"` for Width (this is the closest inch measurement to 7.5x11 cm, if you really want to measure the size by cm you can go to File>Options>Advanced and change the *Show measurements in units of* to *Centimeters*

Now place your content in each of those 4 cells as they are pages and print.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your ingenuity!